# Matching bracket could not be found - Bracket Highlighter package

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I get the following error message when parsing the code below.

[image: it looks like this]

How can I address it?

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    var wordlist = [ "environment", "company", "government", "face", "race", "plant", "fire", "matter", "state", "cause", "reason", "concern", "bear", "raise", "subject", "planet", "article", "education", "purpose", "arm", "object", "amount", "rest", "process", "research", "respect", "influence", "deal", "notice", "support", "generation", "population", "industry", "career", "opportunity", "behavior", "reality", "tear", "issue", "detail", "limit", "challenge", "advance", "benefit", "cure", "expert", "species", "appearance", "character", "quality", "resource", "method", "movement", "instance", "variety", "match", "figure", "stick", "beat", "approach", "Freedom", "tradition", "adventure", "crime", "aspect", "solution", "account", "block", "range", "demage", "supply", "demand", "lie", "spread", "feed", "youth", "soil", "equipment", "term", "advantage", "board", "fuel", "chat", "trick", "attack", "attempt", "exchange", "hide", "gain", "exist", "organism", "emotion", "belief", "economy", "discovery", "rate", "suit", "court", "pressure", "risk", "progress", "escape", "measure", "decrease", "seek", "humanity", "enemy", "grain", "surface", "sickness", "possibility", "crisis", "strategy", "custom", "origin", "introduction", "trust", "credit", "mention", "handle", "element", "entertainment", "imagination", "failure", "mine", "export", "award", "battle", "discipline", "sort", "feature", "lack", "desire", "regret", "freeze", "intelligence", "insect", "automobile", "region", "climate", "protection", "factor", "principle", "theory", "labor", "function", "access", "alarm", "struggle", "prove", "author", "client", "victim", "disaster", "muscle", "instrument", "sculpture", "impact", "popularity", "mystery", "spot", "broadcast", "praise", "link", "steal", "mankind", "ancestor", "tongue", "vocabulary", "section", "mission", "row", "reward", "wound", "survey", "contrast", "conduct", "stretch", "release", "rescue", "addict", "soul", "personality", "novel", "passage", "concept", "scale", "agenda", "explanation", "revolution", "weapon", "patience", "fund", "witness", "stare", "vehicle", "atmosphere", "basis", "edge", "therapy", "insurance", "decade", "delight", "charge", "aim", "request", "comment", "debate", "defeat", "strike", "astronaut", "genius", "charity", "prison", "series", "appointment", "track", "code", "lecture", "aid", "harm", "prejudice", "transfer", "fascinate", "frustrate", "identity", "substance", "physics", "motion", "laboratory", "conclusion", "phrase", "excitement", "miracle", "threat", "harvest", "review", "grab", "puzzle", "claim", "leisure", "literature", "privacy", "duty", "poverty", "policy", "improvement", "expectation", "fantasy", "destruction", "comfort", "regard", "swing", "manufacture", "misunderstand", "companion", "destination", "aptitude", "statue", "means", "religion", "column", "carbon dioxide", "shelter", "profit", "poison", "anger", "thrill", "conflict", "rent", "freshman", "facility", "peninsular", "oxygen", "layer", "explosion", "pace", "incident", "photography", "make-up", "guard", "dust", "sacrifice", "purchase", "construct", "conductor", "wildlife", "summit", "horizon", "clue", "assignment", "faith", "hunger", "trend", "fault", "bomb", "institute", "display", "glance", "reserve", "scholar", "palm", "horn", "arrow", "device", "mixture", "highway", "habitat", "agriculture", "civilization", "gravity", "context", "protest", "sink", "swallow", "pole", "raft", "fare", "quantity", "authority", "judgement", "statement", "tension", "seal", "sum", "panic", "trail", "exhibit", "grant", "guarantee", "belonging", "evidence", "fossil", "biology", "semester", "anxiety", "shame", "famine", "bar", "ease", "suicide", "shoot", "transport", "estimate", "lay", "globe", "shadow", "majority", "association", "journal", "chore", "procedure", "shortage", "intention", "violence", "string", "border", "dump", "encounter", "neglect", "ambassador", "dirt", "property", "income", "category", "circumstance", "equality", "election", "extinction", "remark", "deposit", "cycle", "chase", "ruin", "forgive", "priest", "organ", "telescope", "sword", "welfare", "tourism", "tone", "theme", "preparation", "junk", "whistle", "orbit", "stare", "forbid", "permit", "crew", "expense", "era", "emission", "disorder", "conference", "clay", "channel", "statistics", "command", "pose", "arrest", "leap", "slap", "punish", "bush", "ash", "agency", "document", "tax", "trial", "occasion", "capacity", "iron", "stuff", "import", "venture", "cast", "dislike", "adjust", "union", "pottery", "remains", "surgery", "philosophy", "myth", "stock", "pile", "trap", "shade", "turn", "resort", "vacuum", "dye", "drag", "supreme", "mechanical", "miserable", "bitter", "promising", "sensible", "lively", "liquid", "infect", "terrify", "scold", "strengthen", "skip", "tug", "clap", "descendent", "pupil", "beard", "committee", "carbohydrate", "fortune", "entrance", "alley", "colony", "boundary", "arrival", "consequence", "bargain", "abuse", "roar", "harsh", "register", "actual", "ban", "eager", "forecast", "diligent", "psychology", "capable", "politics", "pale", "prospect", "abstract", "strain", "resident", "minister", "millionaire", "assembly", "germ", "particle", "tide", "legend", "masterpiece", "opinion", "obstacle", "hardship", "farewell", "funeral", "murder", "burst", "ecosystem", "spacecraft", "comet", "chemistry", "cooper", "drawer", "council", "district", "deed", "fame", "breakdown", "dimension", "flame", "counsel", "urge", "workforce", "dynasty", "monster", "gym", "warehouse", "avenue", "volcano", "basin", "barrier", "fee", "triangle", "fusion", "trigger", "vow", "peel", "surgeon", "sympathy", "thirst", "territory", "reunification", "storage", "session", "scholarship", "privilege", "rival", "sponsor", "stem", "hook", "harness", "plot", "nun", "mummy", "monument", "paradise", "mercy", "nightmare", "nerve", "nutrition", "moisture", "motorcycle", "outcome", "millennium", "arise", "meantime", "pioneer", "historian", "geography", "hydrogen", "lava", "livestock", "fishery", "irrigation", "institution", "frame", "logic", "goodwill", "horror", "heritage", "yield", "idiom", "empire", "fate", "feather", "evolution", "fermentation", "drought", "excursion", "encyclopedia", "diameter", "cube", "cone", "feedback", "decline", "strip", "suspect", "archaeologist", "attoney", "sleeve", "caterpillar", "cereal", "mud", "cliff", "cabin", "architecture", "democracy", "administration", "assumption", "burden", "polish", "sow", "spokesperson", "sophomore", "kindergarten", "tribe", "breeze", "scenery", "wetland", "honesty", "thrift", "temper", "signature", "transaction", "flavor", "slope", "cruise", "freelancer", "jaw", "sermon", "route", "ranch", "rainfall", "lottery", "sequence", "necessity", "productivity", "salvation", "nap", "prey", "refund", "spill", "minority", "pedestrian", "physician", "frost", "glacier", "galaxy", "molecule", "headline", "midst", "guidance", "grief", "greed", "lyric", "stain", "loan", "embryo", "fetus", "elbow", "flesh", "fiber", "detergent", "feast", "expedition", "exception", "portion", "dignity", "finance", "drill", "screw", "scoop", "colleague", "closet", "aircraft", "bay", "voyage", "biotechnology", "budget", "proof", "affection", "courtesy", "viewpoint", "defect", "admission", "compliment", "nurture", "celebrity", "autograph", "accountant", "profession", "appliance", "ceiling", "cathedral", "canal", "subscription", "criticism", "aggression", "beam", "charm", "highlight", "halt", "mammal", "warrior", "republic", "spice", "lumber", "suburb", "cemetery", "intersection", "tuition", "yearbook", "commerce", "telecommunication", "usage", "glow", "wrinkle", "personnel", "journalist", "pulse", "sensation", "sewage", "allowance", "altitude", "phenomenon", "depression", "reconciliation", "spear", "shield", "breed", "bump", "spark", "dawn", "lap", "liver", "plume", "microscope", "windshield", "outlet", "jail", "monastery", "corps", "immigration", "perimeter", "perspective", "nonsense", "litter", "candidate", "gender", "faucet", "bullet", "equator", "hell", "congestion", "division", "extent", "errand", "anniversary", "dismay", "substitute", "transplant", "weep", "cosmos", "counterpart", "debris", "mural", "barn", "dialect", "constitution", "consensus", "conscience", "disgrace", "destiny", "gospel", "blossom", "contract", "shift", "ankle", "core", "asset", "artifact", "workout", "circulation", "symptom", "geometry", "advert", "reception", "bias", "bud", "pound", "compound", "audition", "refugee", "souvenir", "fountain", "harbor", "scent", "blueprint", "affair", "justice", "ambition", "meditation", "absence", "triumph", "wind", "grasp", "foretell", "mechanic", "accessory", "currency", "iceberg", "thermometer", "rod", "portrait", "riddle", "shortcut", "tutor", "draft", "sweat", "throne", "retail", "giggle", "monk", "referee", "opponent", "bulb", "attic", "landfill", "mist", "certificate", "flaw", "mischief", "paradox", "proportion", "remedy", "frown", "decay", "bride", "co-worker", "mustache", "weed", "moss", "parcel", "aisle", "biography", "debt", "liberty", "zeal", "superstition", "flock", "drip", "echo", "bough", "dew", "beverage", "cradle", "cottage", "dormitory", "astronomy", "missile", "compensation", "criterion", "blunder", "scandal", "suspicion", "dispute", "bang", "niece", "bridegroom", "casualty", "beast", "ecology", "tag", "interval", "margin", "checkup", "publicity", "coincidence", "contradiction", "caution", "revenge", "sneeze", "spectacle", "auditorium", "patriot", "peasant", "meadow", "hay", "kettle", "baggage", "basement", "enrollment", "compassion", "moderation", "reputation", "scarcity", "switch", "thorn", "banner", "pavement", "outlook", "conviction", "ignorance", "bliss", "gratitude", "boredom", "inflation", "foam", "shed", "confine", "diabetes", "flutter", "present", "draw", "lose", "provide", "allow", "consider", "realize", "mean", "patient", "ancient", "individual", "positive", "genetic", "likely", "still", "relax", "suppose", "require", "affect", "add", "involve", "prevent", "fine", "material", "various", "normal", "unique", "creative", "negative", "eventually", "treat", "describe", "suggest", "accept", "achieve", "avoid", "remain", "reduce", "male/female", "essential", "tiny", "recently", "particular", "similar", "besides", "perform", "occur", "depend", "belong", "contain", "suffer", "encourage", "reflect", "separate", "calm", "polite", "active", "disabled", "available", "merely", "survive", "satisfy", "determine", "establish", "advertise", "compare", "recognize", "fit", "lower", "commercial", "complex", "ordinary", "aware", "responsible", "otherwise", "gather", "manage", "apply", "replace", "appreciate", "refer", "content", "folk", "medium", "direct", "due", "effective", "entire", "familiar", "nevertheless", "succeed", "prefer", "predict", "discuss", "relate", "ignore", "pollute", "mass", "senior", "valuable", "willing", "proper", "specific", "private", "apart", "attend", "preserve", "remind", "respond", "argue", "advise", "organize", "capital", "moral", "potential", "pleasant", "confident", "typical", "solar", "somewhat", "overcome", "behave", "observe", "participate", "publish", "connect", "complain", "disappoint", "current", "worth", "brief", "efficient", "mental", "incredible", "approximately", "enable", "attract", "confuse", "compete", "contribute", "refuse", "maintain", "remove", "rough", "enormous", "constant", "realistic", "virtual", "ethical", "regardless", "impress", "bother", "embarrass", "injure", "surround", "identify", "inclined", "novel", "opposite", "shy", "curious", "rude ", "accurate", "flat", "somewhat", "bury", "celebrate", "insist", "intend", "indicate", "locate", "endanger", "narrow", "characteristic", "tough", "convenient", "significant", "independent", "frequent", "barely", "persuade", "convince", "recommend", "disagree", "promote", "explore", "consume", "consist", "spiritual", "military", "helpless", "artistic", "tropical", "nuclear", "furthermore", "frighten", "obtain", "extend", "rely", "hire", "announce", "represent", "analyze", "plain", "vast", "suitable", "critical", "indifferent", "unexpected", "aside", "deliver", "vary", "expose", "react", "recover", "heal", "memorize", "bound", "firm", "chief", "precious", "terrific", "practice", "appropriate", "seldom", "blame", "vote", "arrange", "adapt", "combine", "disturb", "reveal", "nominate", "ideal", "contrary", "smooth", "exact", "rare", "useless", "likewise", "attach", "select", "amaze", "discourage", "relieve", "admit", "routine", "former", "formal", "reasonable", "legal", "tremendous", "depressed", "high-tech", "accordingly", "bend", "annoy", "invade", "wander", "insure", "bless", "afford", "lean", "civil", "distant", "steady", "vital", "ordinary", "artificial", "seemingly", "crash", "delay", "appeal", "operate", "motivate", "qualify", "apologize", "awake", "representative", "marine", "extreme", "remote", "ultimate", "expressive", "overnight", "rid", "float", "weigh", "declare", "capture", "include", "interact", "devote", "evil", "alternative", "broad", "cruel", "primary", "usual", "undoubtedly", "deserve", "owe", "defend", "obey", "examine", "expand", "transform", "commit", "secure", "rapid", "rural", "anxious", "ashamed", "thoughtful", "readily", "collapse", "crawl", "drown", "absorb", "propose", "criticize", "differ", "infant", "blank", "contemporary", "inner", "elderly", "gloomy", "severe", "namely", "yell", "chew", "pour", "admire", "concentrate", "settle", "translate", "fellow", "instant", "generous", "wealthy", "visual", "previous", "awful", "abruptly", "sweep", "submit", "donate", "define", "interrupt", "pursue", "evolve", "relative", "permanent", "precise", "brilliant", "luxurious", "organic", "royal", "aloud", "possess", "conserve", "inform", "assume", "emphasize", "adopt", "pretend", "classic", "sufficient", "strict", "festive", "dramatic", "delicate", "desperate", "scarcely", "oppose", "exhaust", "awaken", "acquire", "occupy", "found", "employ", "ritual", "solid", "grand", "tragic", "ridiculous", "conscious", "careless", "alike", "pray", "weaken", "toss", "simmarize", "quit", "objective", "executive", "household", "primitive", "passive", "passionate", "identical", "fortunate", "fashionable", "remarkable", "modify", "calculate", "eliminate", "illustrate", "isolate", "accomplish", "distinguish", "grave", "bold", "guilty", "considerable", "annual", "continuous", "accustomed", "ethnic", "historic", "overweight", "verbal", "visible", "sensitive", "cheerful", "sour", "classify", "depict", "deny", "rob", "engage", "endure", "enhance", "fulfill", "stir", "corporation", "ingredient", "instinct", "insight", "ethic", "creation", "landscape", "craft", "coverage", "filter", "merit", "despair", "assist", "weave", "split", "punch", "rub", "install", "inspire", "resist", "starve", "specialize", "considerate", "enthusiastic", "continual", "complicated", "diverse", "intensive", "literary", "trait", "enrich", "pastime", "confirm", "volume", "emerge", "wilderness", "depart", "wagon", "creep", "daydream", "herd", "drift", "stroke", "veterinarian", "flash", "pause", "spin", "launch", "adjourn", "accompany", "unite", "decorate", "superior", "sorrowful", "swift", "vivid", "valid", "weird", "urban", "strive", "undergo", "tolerate", "smash", "spoil", "tempt", "reject", "uncover", "initial", "sincere", "jealous", "optimistic", "prior", "occasional", "prone", "scratch", "proceed", "resume", "fasten", "lessen", "overlook", "overwhelm", "resemble", "humble", "genuine", "graceful", "extraordinary", "fertile", "exotic", "halfway", "rank", "hatch", "embrace", "investigate", "interfere", "imply", "imitate", "fade", "concrete", "dynamic", "bare", "atomic", "conventional", "eternal", "automatic", "approve", "consult", "diagnose", "congratulate", "boast", "dedicate", "dare", "abandon", "absolute", "intellectual", "alien", "loose", "pure", "raw", "selfish", "worship", "trace", "wreck", "nod", "tickle", "wipe", "compose", "elect", "spare", "steep", "spectacular", "prime", "worthwhile", "subjective", "voluntary", "suck", "sting", "scatter", "pronounce", "symbolize", "restrict", "retire", "minimum", "noble", "criminal", "outstanding", "outgoing", "partial", "mutural", "overall", "mislead", "pat", "paralyze", "shatter", "recite", "renew", "prohibit", "adolescent", "latter", "gigantic", "infinite", "innocent", "loyal", "grateful", "domestic", "crush", "grin", "disguise", "exclaim", "digest", "impose", "interpret", "dim", "courageous", "dense", "countless", "costly", "crucial", "distort", "deadly", "crack", "ache", "chant", "chop", "choke", "alter", "conquer", "cheat", "faint", "dull", "competent", "dumb", "vague", "urgent", "temporary", "spit", "sparkle", "fold", "startle", "stun", "tumble", "soak", "stimulate", "slim", "spacious", "sociable", "stiff", "stubborn", "striking", "subtle", "seize", "slam", "scrub", "leak", "recall", "resolve", "reproduce", "mature", "memorial", "editorial", "slight", "massive", "numerous", "prominent", "naked", "insult", "erupt", "overflow", "perceive", "demonstrate", "dismiss", "distribute", "invest", "foul", "frank", "magnificent", "horrible", "immediate", "gradual", "internal", "grind", "hop", "excel", "flatter", "irritate", "hesitate", "hinder", "improvise", "fearful", "envious", "extensive", "faraway", "fluent", "fatal", "edible", "drain", "doom", "collide", "contaminate", "detect", "dictate", "accuse", "evaluate", "deliberate", "principal", "alert", "adequate", "desirable", "superficial", "controversial", "cease", "duplicate", "carve", "snap", "cherish", "deprive", "designate", "vocal", "terminal", "solitary", "vain", "apparent", "trivial", "vertical", "undone", "shrug", "sigh", "scream", "blend", "await", "cancel", "correspond", "worsen", "parental", "shallow", "profound", "peculiar", "monotonous", "messy", "random", "squeeze", "tilt", "stumble", "anticipate", "supervise", "violate", "transmit", "priceless", "marvelous", "modest", "neutral", "literal", "ongoing", "inclined", "noticeable", "reform", "reverse", "kneel", "shrink", "soar", "offend", "refine", "restore", "intent", "juvenile", "intimate", "furious", "fundamental", "immune", "linguistic", "quote", "overhear", "shave", "pierce", "plunge", "reap", "prevail", "perish", "outlaw", "ceramic", "fragile", "flexible", "harmonious", "habitual", "destined", "graze", "splash", "originate", "instruct", "inherit", "nourish", "flourish", "exceed", "exclude", "wholesale", "chilly", "dizzy", "distinct", "drastic", "fierce", "descend", "derive", "recur", "cooperate", "generalize", "foster", "damp", "fake", "vegetarian", "cunning", "disposable", "lunar", "arrogant", "absurd", "beloved", "gamble", "tremble", "inhabit", "multiply", "exaggerate", "diminish", "discard", "omit", "stable", "antique", "cosmetic", "tender", "decent", "rotten", "odd", "commute", "divorce", "dwell", "bleed", "swear", "prescribe", "conceal", "confess", "discriminate", "inferior", "definite", "rational", "pessimistic", "disgusting", "striped", "bounce", "glitter", "bleach", "applaud", "prosper", "comprehend", "constitute", "suspend", "leftover", "obvious", "abnormal", "awkward", "holy", "witty", "bald", "yawn", "trim", "withdraw", "sprain", "hasten", "cope", "inquire", "certify", "distract", "oval", "ripe", "resentful", "probable", "athletic", "checked", "retreat", "tease", "swell", "dip", "astonish", "vomit", "contend", "justify", "idle", "radical", "bilingual", "gorgeous", "solemn", "homesick", "ironic", "notify", "converse", "confront", "convert", "revise", "dominate", "sustain", "fluid", "liberal", "utmost", "baggy", "allergic", "oral", "coherent", "skeptical" ];
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it work with short arrays or when each item is in a separate line?

Comment: This happens when your Regular Expression Button is selected. Once De-Select that button which is in the bottom-left  corner of your sublime OR Press Alt+R. Then It will search. (This is a solution to the problem, But even i wonder why its happening like this.)

Answer (score 6):

The error message on the screenshot tells you exactly what’s wrong: the length of the string is beyond Bracket Highlighter’s [search threshold](http://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/#search_threshold).

> The search threshold determines how many characters BH will search through to find matching brackets before giving up. This setting only affects auto-matching and not on-demand calls from the command palette and menu. By default, this value is very conservative and can be increased.

You can increase the threshold in the package settings, but that can have an impact on performance.

**Example:**

```
// Character threshold to search
"search_threshold": 5000,
```

Comment: Thanks. Then how can I edit settings? I tried to Preferences>Settings and type that code, and then I got an error.

Comment: Those are the general Sublime Text settings. BracketHighlighter settings are in `Preferences > Package Settings > BracketHighlighter > Bracket Settings`. If you got an error, your settings are saved as valid JSON. Make sure the above settings are *inside* the curly braces.

Comment: Or just set "ignore threshold" setting to "true". Default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

for turn off this, you can go this settings -> "Preferences > Package Settings > BracketHighlighter > Bracket Settings" and in left side write = ""ignore_threshold": true", with this you turn off this problem, you will not see that problem, i think that.

Sorry for my English =)